# How do I get a picturebox in another thread to show up

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I am trying to create a picturebox in another thread and have it show up in my form. The creation seems to be fine, but I can never see it.

This is my code for the picture box:

```
 Public Sub reading_data_bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

        Dim temp_box As New PictureBox
        With temp_box
            .Image = My.Resources.preloader_blue_ball
            .Size = New Size(200, 200)
            .Location = New Point(100, 100)
            .Visible = True
            .BackColor = Color.Transparent
            .Parent = Main
            .BringToFront()
           End With

         Application.DoEvents()

 End Sub
```

Of course I call it with:

```
reading_data_bw.RunWorkerAsync()
```

Comment: GUI work has to be done on the GUI thread.  Nothing here shows that this needs to be in a background worker.  Get rid of that DoEvents.

Comment: I realize the need is not shown here, but there is a need and this is how I'm trying to execute it. So you're telling me I can not create another control on a different thread and have it show up in my form?

Comment: Fix your RunWorkerCompleted event handler, you cannot ignore the e.Error property.  Then you'll have a shot at fixing your bug.  Adding Main.ShowDialog() might give insight as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Hans, but e.Error = nothing and e.Result = nothing. Is it possible and I'm just doing it wrong or is it not possible and I should try something else?

Comment: Basically, I have a data process that takes about 5 seconds to execute and I want to show the user that something is still going on in the background because the program becomes unresponsive while it is waiting for the data to be returned.

Comment: OK, so it looks like I should keep my picturebox in my UI thread and do the database work in the background worker. However, I have 100's of these database calls and I don't want to put each one in a different background worker. And I can't re-use the same background worker since each database operation is different. Even if I pass it arguments, a different operation needs to be performed based on the data read result. So re-use is not possible.

Comment: Five seconds is not very long.  You could just use a marquee stye progressbar to show the app is busy

Comment: What exactly do you mean by marqueee style?